# Debugging Memory Mapped Files

Tags: c#, c++, winapi, shared-memory, memory-mapped-files

I’m developing a `.NET` program which suppose to be communicate with other existing program in same machine using Shared Memory (Memory Mapped Files), The existing program itself include a native `dll` and `.NET` wrapper / bridge `dll` which I could consume to communicate with the other program.

The thing is the other program is very buggy and the source codes of the program and `dll` are long gone, so my goal is to recreate the other program. I could decompile `.NET` `dll` but it just straight `P/Invoke` the native `dll`.

Fortunately, I able to view the memory mapped file with [`System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.MemoryMappedFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile) but that’s all I got, I have no idea in which offset the `dll` read the data from memory mapped file when I call certain functions from it (Most of the time the `dll` only doing read and no write)

I also tried to hook [`CreateFileMapping`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-createfilemappingw), [`OpenFileMapping`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-openfilemappingw) and [`MapViewOfFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-mapviewoffile) in C++ program and call certain functions inside the native `dll` but those hooked function only called once in during initialization and did not trigger when invoke function in `dll` that suppose to read data from memory mapped file. If I dare to guess, the `dll` must be has pointer to the memory mapped file.

So my question, is it possible to put breakpoint or detect when any process attempt to read / write of certain region of memory mapped file? For an instance, I'd like to know whether there's read process or pointer pointing at offset `0xdeadbeef` in my memory mapped file. I'm open to alternative, so let me know if you had any better idea

Comment: A file-mapping object is created once, and commonly mapped exactly once. From then on forward, it's just a junk of memory like any other. It is to be expected, that the file-mapping API calls are hit no more than once. To learn when a region of memory changes, [set a data breakpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-breakpoints#BKMK_set_a_data_breakpoint_native_cplusplus) using your debugger.

Comment: @IInspectable thanks for the reply, I get better understanding as why the API only called once. For debugging, the page that you linked says "If the value is read but not changed, execution doesn't break", I need to track value read since the `dll` is mostly read operation. Also it says it won't work for "The memory location is shared between two or more processes"

Comment: Reading from memory has no observable side-effects. I'm not aware of a way (using a debugger or otherwise) that allows you to get notified about a memory read. Recording a [time-travel debugging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/time-travel-debugging-overview) session is probably your best bet, though I'm not sure how difficult it is to query for memory read operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Memory Mapped File but if the two process share same memory, I believe it has same physical address, if this is true then you could probably use [Cheat Engine](https://cheatengine.org/) with kernel mode.

Just keep in mind that it can cause system instability or crash so make sure to save all your works before proceeding. You can follow this steps:

1. First open one of the program, make sure that "shared memory" is created before proceeding into the next step.
2. Open Cheat Engine, make sure to enable kernel mode for `OpenProcess` in Settings -> Extra and enable kernel debugger in Settings -> Debugger Options (otherwise you won't be able to observe the instructions that access the memory)
3. Open the process in Cheat Engine, select the program that you launched in the first step
4. Now scan the memory inside cheat engine, since you mentioned that you able to view the memory, take out some chunk of bytes that you wish to monitor, change value type to array of byte and scan for those bytes
5. Scan result will appear in the left pane, you might found multiple result, there's only one correct address most of the time and the rest is accidentally match with the value you scan for, right click and select Browse this memory region, make sure that surrounding data match with what you expect
6. Back to main window, double click the correct ones and it will appear on the bottom pane, right click it and select "DBVM Find out what writes or access this address", a dialog will appear (or your system might crash), the most important part is ensure that the physical address there instead appearing at textbox
7. Select access type, you could watch only writes or both read and writes and hit "Start watch" button
8. Every time any process make an attempt to access or write into that memory region, new instruction will appear in the list.

In my opinion, this topic is close to reverse engineering. Since you're open to suggestion, here's my other two cents: if you had a plan to re-create the existing program which emit the data via shared memory and you're developing the client too, why not remake both of them from scratch so you don't have to deal with this?

Comment: thanks for the answer, I tried to follow the steps above, however the extra settings to enable OpenProcess is greyed out as well as kernel debugger too, I already pressed “Make it possible” button and restart my computer but it still greyed out, any ideas? As for your suggestion, there’s multiple existing client that communicate to the other program with memory mapped file, which i don’t intend to rewrite

Comment: After bit searching, it turn out I need to disable Hyper V to get this DBVM work and it work, thanks! edit: upvoted since it helped me and someone downvoted this answer

Answer (score 0):

If you know the specific data address, you can use debuggers like windbg or x64dbg to set hardware data breakpoints. I'm not sure how well that is going to work together with C#, but it is definitely possible.

You can also try to use time travel debugging in windbg, which records a whole execution of the program and allows you to query retroactively when an address was written to.

Comment: Can you please add step by step how i add hardware breakpoint with these tools?